# Equal expected value on measurable sets implies equal distribution?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose we have $X, Y$ random variables defined on $(\Omega, \mathbb B)$ such that $E(XI_B)=E(YI_B)$ for all $B\in \mathbb B$. Is it true that X, Y have the same distribution, i.e. $\mathbb P(X\leq t)=\mathbb P(Y\leq t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$?

I think this is true and I'm trying to prove it by contradiction. Suppose $\mathbb P(X\leq t)< \mathbb P(Y\leq t)$ for some $t$, I want to show $E(XI_{X\leq t})<E(YI_{Y\leq t})$. It's not clear me how to proceed. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only that, but in fact $X=Y$ almost surely.  Hint: take $B = \{X \ge Y\}$ and then $\{X \le Y\}$.